# How to set the default font in Google Closure Library rich text editor

Tags: css, iframe, google-closure, google-closure-library

Google Closure Library editor: [demo](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/editor/editor.html), [documentation](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/namespace_goog_editor.html).

The editable area is an iframe. How can I set the default font of the editable area? Now it is the default font of the browser. I prefer not to put a font tag around the content in the editable area**. That way, I can change the font of my website in the future, without the need to modify every HTML-content written in the editor.

** What I mean by that is something like this:

```
<font size="2" face="georgia, serif"><b>content</b></font>
```

I would prefer just this:

```
<b>content</b>
```

... and then style the editable area of the editor with the georgia font using CSS. That way, the HTML-content (produced by the editor) in my database wouldn't contain a hard-coded font, so I could change the font in the future.

Edit: maybe I should use a `SeamlessField` instead of a `Field` for the editable area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call `makeEditable()` on the `goog.editor.Field`, which creates the iFrame you referenced, the Field fires an event of type `goog.editor.Field.EventType.LOAD`. If you listen to that event, you can pull out the iFrame and toss in a link element to a CSS stylesheet so you can easily modify the content in your editor.

Here's the equivalent of one of my listeners that should get you on the right track. (I didn't check if the `goog.editor.Field` was the target of the event, but I assume it is).

```js
some.namespace.Page.prototype.onEditorLoad_ = function(event) {
  var editor = /** @type {goog.editor.Field} */ (event.target);
  var iFrame = editor.getEditableIframe();
  if (iFrame) {
    var fieldDomHelper = editor.getEditableDomHelper();
    var documentNode =
      fieldDomHelper.getFrameContentDocument(iFrame).documentElement;

    var head = documentNode.getElementsByTagName(goog.dom.TagName.HEAD)[0];
    if (!head) {
      head = fieldDomHelper.createDom(goog.dom.TagName.HEAD);
      goog.dom.insertChildAt(documentNode, head, 0);
    }

    fieldDomHelper.appendChild(
      head,
      fieldDomHelper.createDom(
        goog.dom.TagName.LINK,
        { 'href': '/css/myCSS.css', 'rel': 'stylesheet', 'type': 'text/css' }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, in that CSS file, you can add whatever styling you want. Such as your font change.